# How to restore sent mails from .ost File?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, offline-caching

i recently moved my exchange server (Windows SBS ;D ). Now i have the Problem that there are some sent mails missing in outlook (only sent mails from May 2020).
I activated the Outlook cache exchange mode already years ago.

With the software Outlookviewer i was able do get all my received emails but i cant find my sent emails from may 2020.

Is there any other way how to recover them ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To recover deleted mail items in Exchange, an administrator can use Powershell commands and Exchange Admin panel according to understanding and working.

If Administrator wants to try Powershell commands to recover back emails files, then use the command:

```
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -eq ‘UserMailbox’)} | 
      Set-Mailbox -SingleItemRecoveryEnabled $true -RetainDeletedItemsFor 30
```

Before that Enable the recovery of single items with the help of the following command:

```
    Set-Mailbox -Identity “name of the user” -SingleItemRecoveryEnabled $true
```

Enable the single item recovery and set the retention period of the deleted item for any single user. The following command activates the recovery of the single item and sets the retention period of 30 days.

```
    Set-Mailbox -Identity “name of the user” -SingleItemRecoveryEnabled $true -RetainDeletedItemsFor 30
```

Since more commands are used so you can refer to the [link](http://www.datarecovery.institute/recover-deleted-email-items-exchange-2003-2007-2010-2013/).

Here you find step by step commands and other precautions that need during recovering deleted items.

Comment: Thanks for your commands! The problem is, that I had do restore an old version from the exchange server due to a mistake. My luck was that I had enabled the exchage cache mode. So the only thing i have is my ost file. And I think the commands you provided are just for the server